# VBA rename files - error handling stops working at second iteration

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

My setup in Excel looks like in the picture. The source path is empty so errors are expected.

[image]

When I fire up the code below, it stops at the second iteration with run-time error 75 instead of going to ErrorHandler. Why?

```
Sub Rename_files()

    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = Cells(ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row, 2).Row
    
    Dim i As Long:  For i = 2 To LastRow
        Dim SourcePathName As String: SourcePathName = Cells(i, 1).Value2 & Cells(i, 2).Value2
        Dim TargetPathName As String: TargetPathName = Cells(i, 3).Value2 & Cells(i, 4).Value2
        Dim Result As Range: Set Result = Cells(i, 5)
        
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
        Name SourcePathName As TargetPathName: Result.Value2 = "Done. No errors."
        GoTo NextIteration
        
ErrorHandler:
        Select Case Err.Number
        Case 75:
            Result.Value2 = "Run-time error 75. Path/file access error."
            Err.Clear
        End Select

NextIteration:
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: That is not a valid error handler setup - you should have a `Resume` statement of some kind to reset the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `Goto` and use a proper error handling: [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling).

Also make sure all your `Cells` and `Range` objects are referenced to a worksheet.

```
Option Explicit 

Public Sub Rename_files()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet ' better something like ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row, 2).Row
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        Dim SourcePathName As String
        SourcePathName = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value2 & ws.Cells(i, 2).Value2

        Dim TargetPathName As String
        TargetPathName = ws.Cells(i, 3).Value2 & ws.Cells(i, 4).Value2

        Dim Result As Range
        Set Result = ws.Cells(i, 5)
        
        On Error Resume Next
        Name oldPathFilename As newPathFilename
        Result.Value2 = "Done. No errors."

        Select Case Err.Number
        Case 75:
            Result.Value2 = "Run-time error 75. Path/file access error."
            Err.Clear
        End Select

        On Error Goto 0
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basically what I wanted to achieve.

Thanks for the suggestions.

```
Sub Rename_files()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook:     Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet:    Set sh = wb.Worksheets(RENAME.Name)
    
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = Cells(sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row, 2).Row
    
    Dim i As Long:  For i = 2 To LastRow
        Dim SourcePathName As String: SourcePathName = sh.Cells(i, 1).Value2 & sh.Cells(i, 2).Value2
        Dim TargetPathName As String: TargetPathName = sh.Cells(i, 3).Value2 & sh.Cells(i, 4).Value2
        Dim Result As Range: Set Result = sh.Cells(i, 5)
        
        On Error GoTo -1
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
        
        Name SourcePathName As TargetPathName: Result.Value2 = "Done"
        GoTo NextIteration
        
ErrorHandler:
        Result.Value2 = Err.Description
        Err.Clear
        
NextIteration:
    Next

End Sub
```